# Не работает выбор пункта из выпадающего списка

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Среда: Firefox 47.0.2 + WebDriver 2.53.1

Необходимо в форме регистрации выбрать сначала графу "пол", затем из выпадающего списка, например "мужской". Неработающий код:

```
package com.driver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Listdown {

     static WebDriver driver;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.manage().window().maximize();

         driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&hl=ru&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fpc%3Dtopnav-about-ru");

         driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//strong[text()='Пол']/following-sibling::div/div[@role='listbox'])[1]")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Мужской']/parent::div[@role='option']")).click();
     }
}
```

Не работает метод клика по элементу "Мужской". Xpath пути к элементу в FirePath подсвечивает корректно. Для проверки вывел значение искомого элемента в консоль (изменил немного код через WebElement) - в консоль, как положено, выводится слово "Мужской":

```
WebElement gender = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//strong[text()='Пол']/following-sibling::div/div[@role='listbox'])[1]"));
gender.click();
WebElement genderChose = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Мужской']/parent::div[@role='option']"));
System.out.println(genderChose.getText());
```

Не понятна причина, почему не работает метод click().

Поэкспериментировал на сайте OK.ru. Путем танцев с бубнами сумел выбрать элемент выпадающего списка, но исключительно с применением **Actions** и двойного клика **doubleClick()** по элементу, метод одинарного клика click() в этом коде по-прежнему работать не будет:

```
package com.driver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Listdown {

     static WebDriver driver;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.manage().window().maximize();

         driver.get("https://ok.ru/dk?st.cmd=anonymMain&st.registration=on");
         selectOpt("Country", "Albania");
     }

     public static void selectOpt (String name, String option) {
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//label[text()='%s']/parent::span/following-sibling::div", name))).click();
         Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
         WebElement elemOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//*[@id='country']/option[text()='%s']", option)));
         builder.doubleClick(elemOption).perform();
     }
}
```

В чем может быть причина этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился переустановкой новой версии вебдрайвера.